# Remover de un array el primer valor

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando con codeigniter(php). Si pudieran ponerme como hacerlo de manera clara os lo agradeceria mucho pues soy novatillo.

Esta es mi funcion la cual me trae todos los campos. No lo he hecho yo, estoy de practicas en una empresa.

```
    const TABLE = 'user_role';
const ID_ADMIN = 1;
const ID_CLIENT = 2;
const ID_ARTIST = 3;
const ID_MANAGER = 4;
const ID_TEACHER = 5;
const ID_ATTRACTION = 6;

    public function getAll($onlyId=false){
    $results = $this->db
        ->from(self::TABLE)
        ->get()
        ->result();
    if(!$onlyId){
        return $results;
    }else{
        $items = array();
        foreach($results AS $item){
            $items[$item->id]= $item->name;
        }
        return $items;
    }
}
```

Ese es mi funcion, pero eso trae todo y yo no quiero que me traiga la primera fila (admin).

Comment: Bienvenido Ricardo, deberías pasarte por el [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer como funciona SO. Revisa en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) los apartados [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder obtener buenas respuestas. [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/257941/edit) y añade el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora, así como tus resultados.

Answer (score 1):

```
const TABLE = 'user_role';
const ID_ADMIN = 1;
const ID_CLIENT = 2;
const ID_ARTIST = 3;
const ID_MANAGER = 4;
const ID_TEACHER = 5;
const ID_ATTRACTION = 6;

    public function getAll($onlyId=false){
    $results = $this->db
        ->from(self::TABLE)
        ->get()
        ->result();
    if(!$onlyId){
        array_shift($results);
        return $results;
    }else{
        $items = array();
        foreach($results AS $item){
            $items[$item->id]= $item->name;
        }

        array_shift($items);
        return $items;
    }
}
```

Podrías usar la función `array_shift()` para devolver el `array`. Lo que hace esta función de **PHP** es sustraer el primer registro del array que le pasas como parámetro.

**Documentación:** [array_shift()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: Lo que hace `array_shift()` literalmente es  *extraer* más que *eliminar*, la ayuda en inglés es más clara al repecto: **Shift an element off the beginning of array**, por lo tanto la función  ¿no debería devolver `$results` e `$items` respectivamente tras usar `array_shift($results)` y  `array_shift($items)`?  Sino lo que hará será devolver **solo** el primer elemento.

Comment: @Fly Tienes toda la razón, eso devolvería el valor sustraído. Modifico el código para que devuelva el array - el valor sustraído.

Comment: @Fly Ahora sí que devolvería el array menos el valor sustraído. También he cambiado "borrar" por "sustraer" es más exacto.